# Does Eater of Virtue works with tokens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a token is exiled with [Eater of Virtue](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Eater%20of%20Virtue), does the equiped creature has the listed abilities?

I wonder because tokens aren't really cards...

Comment: I'm not sure how to work this into my answer yet, but "tokens aren't really cards" is understating the situation, like saying "vegetarian food doesn't usually contain meat". That distinction is the entire point.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I'm glad it's so evident for you :)

Answer (score 13):

**Eater of Virtules only grants abilities from exiled cards, not tokens.**

Eater of Virtues' third ability says

> As long as **a card** exiled with Eater of Virtue has flying, equipped creature has flying. The same is true for first strike, double strike, deathtouch, haste, hexproof, indestructible, lifelink, menace, protection, reach, trample, and vigilance.

Tokens are not cards, so the ability does not work with tokens. In addition, even if the wording was different, it could not work with tokens anyway, because tokens cannot continue to exist outside of the battlefield. This is because of [rule 111.7](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Token):

> A token that’s in a zone other than the battlefield ceases to exist. This is a state-based action; see rule 704. (Note that if a token changes zones, applicable triggered abilities will trigger before the token ceases to exist.)

If a token equipped with Eater of Virtues dies, it will cease to exist immediately after going to the graveyard, before Eater of Virtues' triggered ability resolves and tries to move it to exile.

Comment: Not even considering the fact that tokens *can't* be exiled with Eater of Virtues. It doesn't replace dying with exile, it triggers when a creature dies, so the token would cease to exist from the graveyard before it gets exiled. (But after the ability triggers.)

Comment: You're right, I've fixed that part. I think when I wrote it, I wasn't thinking about the fact that Eater of Virtues' exile effect was on a death trigger.

Comment: Still a good answer even without it. There are multiple reasons it won't work, I wasn't going to fault you for not listing all of them.